# Double sized icons in UI?

Tags: python

I want to implement bigger buttons, with icons at it. Preferable double size of what we currently have. I can scale the button height by row.scale_y . But the size of icons is hardcoded to 16 pixels. Can be found in the source\blender\editors\include\UI_interface_icons.h

But you can scale the UI with the dpi settings in the user preferences. And then the icons becomes bigger with the rest of the UI. Question is, is there a Python way to scale icons bigger for just one UI element?

And in case not, is there another way to implement buttons with bigger icons by Python? I would even be happy about hints how to do this in the C code :)

[image: Bigger sized icon buttons?]

Comment: I don't know about the icon reso/dpi,  but may look for "custom icons" as tutorials (seen some using GL) or starting here https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_release/bpy.utils.previews.html#custom-icon-example

Comment: Thanks o.g. . I had this in my fingers before. But also this custom icon gets scaled down to 16x16. Even when i use a bigger one. So that's unfortunately not a solution. But thanks for the tip with GL. Maybe that's a walkable path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still figuring out how to selectively edit icon size, but the line and file you are looking for is `#define ICON_DEFAULT_HEIGHT 16` and `#define ICON_DEFAULT_WIDTH_16` in `UI_interface_icons.h`. For example, changing this height and width to 32 instead of 16 will double all of your icons; it would be ideal if you're scaling the rest of your interface (e.g. button padding) proportionately. This works for Blender source version 2.79. Hope this helps!